# APIGEE Application level

Tags: apigee

I am trying to access a collection using my application client_id, and client secret as follows:

https://api.usergrid.com/my_org/my_app/my_collection?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXX

I get the following error:

{
    "error":"unauthorized",
    "timestamp":1416953278007,
    "duration":0,
    "exception":"org.apache.usergrid.rest.exceptions.SecurityException",
    "error_description":"No application access authorized"
   }

Is there a setting in my app somewhere that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an access code.  This is explained here: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-users-and-application-clients.  To use the access token, follow the instructions on this page: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-api-requests

Comment: Thanks! I did look at: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/authenticating-api-requests and that's where it notes that I can authenticate using just the app client_id and client_secret. It works with my organization client_id and client_secret but not with my app credentials. This is why I think I have to set a property somewhere in the console...